# Google Calendar API event invitation not sending to non-gmail account using Service Account authentication

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am using google service account to implement google calendar api to my web application.

As far as I researched lot of documents but not found exact solution.

I tried following things:

1) Using "**OAuth 2.0 client IDs**" credentials.
   - I can create event in google calendar.
   - Also email notifications sending to all attendees (including non-gmail account).
   - But drawback is it must require google authentication (google log in).
   - As per my requirement anyone can create in google calendar event without google login.

2) Using "**Service account**" credentials.
   - I can create event in google calendar.
   - sending email notification to gmail addresses only among attendees.
   - No need of google log in.

I preferred the second way.

```
$rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
$scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();

$scope->setType("user");
$scope->setValue("xxx@gmail.com");
$scope->setValue("xxxxxxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
$rule->setScope($scope);
$rule->setRole("owner");

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Calendar Service");
$client->setAuthConfig('service_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$calendar_service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarList = $calendar_service->calendarList;

$event_data = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => "Service Account Test Event",
    'location' => 'Los Angeles',
    'description' => 'This is extrieme test event',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2017-09-13T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
      'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2017-09-13T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
    'recurrence' => array(
      'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
      array('email' => 'xxx@yopmail.com'),
      array('email' => 'xxx@gmail.com'),
      array('email' => 'xxx@hotmail.com'),
    ),
    'reminders' => array(
      'useDefault' => FALSE,
      'overrides' => array(
        array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
        array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
      ),
    )
));

$calendarId = 'dsfsdfasdfxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';

$sendNotifications = array('sendNotifications' => true);

$event_response = $calendar_service->events->insert($calendarId, $event_data, $sendNotifications);
```

My only problem is I cannot send event notification to non-gmail account means email doesn't received by (hotmail.com,yopmail.com,etc...)

Please suggest is there any way to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I've removed the fullCalendar tag from your question because nothing in the question relates to the fullCalendar library. Please don't use tags that have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: And..."Please suggest is there any way to solve this issue.". What issue? You haven't mentioned a problem, or any error messages, or anything at all. You've just shown some code. There's something in the title but it's too vague - proper full details of the problem should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the problem is with the only **"yopmail.com"** domain. For other email domains it is working fine. The google event invitation is working on google notification standards and norms.